# Need to fetch some data from SQL Server and display it into a textview

Tags: android, sql-server

I need to fetch data from my database here is my code for fetching data

```
Connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                try{
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM Driver WHERE UID='" + UID + "'";
                    Statement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        UDI = rs.getString("FirstName");
                        TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                        Name.setText(UDI);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is, whenever I click the button, nothing is being fetched.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }` exceptional exception catching ... 0. search fo similar question before asking ...1. at least log an exception ... 2. do not use javax.sql on android ...

Comment: I'm fairly new to android so I still don't know how to log an exception. I have searched for hours how to do this but I was still unsuccessful. That is why I resulted on asking for help.

Comment: Use this `Log.e("TAGCLASSNAME",""+e.getMessage());` for loging